# Reset Android settings to stock

Tags: settings, restore, 7.1-nougat

Is there anyway to restore all the settings as if I just set up the device? I don't need to factory reset and purge all files and apps, I just want to reset the settings

Device : Moto G5S Plus, Android 7.1.1

Comment: Does it mean, clean accounts too or just: display, network, security, notification and sound settings only. Be specific about which settings are making you think you wanna reset

Comment: Moto G5S Plus, Android 7.1.1. Literally all the settings afforded to me.

Comment: AFAIK not possible without factory reset

Comment: That's pretty retarded...